# Prime number calculation algorithm speed makes no sense

Tags: python, c, algorithm

My problem is fairly simple, I  am trying to calculate the nth prime number, however between the two methods that I have coded, the one that I expect to run faster appears to be slower. Which honestly makes no sense. I initially coded the solution using python, here is the code:

```
import time
import math


start1 = time.time()
primes = [2]
count = 3
primes_len = 1
while primes_len <= 10001:
    is_prime = True
    for i in range(primes_len):
        if count % primes[i] == 0:
            is_prime = False
            break
    if is_prime:
        primes_len += 1
        primes.append(count)
    count += 2
print(primes[-1])
end1 = time.time()

start2 = time.time()

listPrime = [2]
upTo = 1000000
isPrime = True

for sayi in range(3, upTo, 2):
    for bölen in range(2,int(math.sqrt(sayi)+1)):

        if (sayi % bölen) == 0:
            isPrime = False
            break

        else:
            isPrime = True

    if isPrime == True :
        listPrime.append(sayi)
        if len(listPrime) == 10001:
            break

print(listPrime[-1])

end2 = time.time()
print(end1-start1)
print(end2-start2)
```

Even though I expected the first algorithm to run faster(since it only tests for known primes and thus should require less calculation), the second one was significantly more eficcient. Thinking it was a weird python thing that caused the unexpected result, I coded them both in C, here it is:

The first one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("You must provide one argument as the nth prime to calculate");
        return 0;
    }

    clock_t begin = clock();
    long LIMIT = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);;
    int count = 3;
    int primes_found = 1;
    int primes[LIMIT];
    primes[0] = 2;
    int is_prime; 
    while(primes_found < LIMIT){
        is_prime = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < primes_found; i++){
            if(count % primes[i] == 0){
                is_prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(is_prime == 1){
            primes[primes_found] = count;
            primes_found += 1;
        }
        count += 2;
    }
    printf("%d\n", primes[LIMIT - 1]);
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%f\n", time_spent);
    return 0;
}
```

The second one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("You must provide one argument as the nth prime to calculate");
        return 0;
    }

    clock_t begin = clock();
    long LIMIT = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);;
    int count = 3;
    int primes_found = 1;
    int primes[LIMIT];
    primes[0] = 2;
    int is_prime;
    while(primes_found < LIMIT){
        is_prime = 1;
        for(int i = 2; i <= (int) sqrt(count); i++){
            if(count % i == 0){
                is_prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(is_prime == 1){
            primes[primes_found] = count;
            primes_found += 1;
        }
        count += 2;
    }
    printf("%d\n", primes[LIMIT - 1]);
    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%f\n", time_spent);
    return 0;
}
```

Which behaved the same way. Honestly, this makes absolutely no sense to me, would appreciate any opinions on it.

Comment: Simple: the first one doesn't stop at sqrt(n).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the difference between loops

```
    for(int i = 0; i < primes_found; i++){
```

And

```
    for(int i = 2; i <= (int) sqrt(count); i++){
```

When the number being tested for a prime, let us call `test`, the first iterates against all known smaller primes `primes[i]`.  When `primes[i]*primes[i] > test`, that is wasted time.

The second loop iterates all values up to `sqrt(test)`.  This is inefficient in that many division candidates are not primes themselves.

Apparently, the inefficiency of the first is worst.

---

An alternative to is iterate using the prime list, but stop when `primes[i]*primes[i] > test` <sup>1</sup>.

Also see [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) for  a likely faster approach.

---

<sup>1</sup> Even better: use `primes[i] > test/primes[i]` to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 0):

In your first one, you forgot to only go up to the square root.